# Python not writing to the log

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I have a python script like this:

```
log_file = r"upload_log_daily.txt"



log_file = open(log_file,"w+")  
...some python statements   
old_stdout = sys.stdout
stdout = log_file
log_file .close()
```

But nothing gets written to the log, although it prints to the console. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a local variable called stdout.

Try this:

```
log_file = r"upload_log_daily.txt"


log_file = open(log_file, "w+")

old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = log_file
print('hi')
log_file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, but still doesnt write. It stopped printing to the console though. Do I need to flush() the buffer?

Comment: Try `print('hi', Flush=True)`

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using log_file.write()? You just have to use something that you want to log as a parameter, but you 'd have to use the write function several times for logging. Ex:

```
log_file = open(log_file, "w+")
while ("some condition"):
   log_file.write("output value")

log_file.close() #Once you don't need to log things anymore
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename="log_file.log",
format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
filemode='w')
 
#Creating an object
logger=logging.getLogger()
 
#Setting the threshold of logger to DEBUG
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#Any python code
logger.info("Information to write in log file")
```

You can directly import logging and use this code to write in log.